# How to prepend front controller servlet mapping to urls in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, front-controller

I have a simple java web application running in Tomcat.

In it, FrontController.java servlet has mapping `@WebServlet("/controller/*")`. So, in order to fire the servlet, I need my every url to start with `/controller/`. I need to be able to display images on pages images are stored outside container, so that I write them to `OutputStream`). But if I write my src urls like `${pageContext.request.contextPath}images/picture.jpg` then the resulting url will be obviously `localhost:8080/rootFolder/images/picture.jpg` and not the `localhost:8080/rootFolder/controller/images/picture.jpg`.

To load these files I can either manually prepend `controller/` after every `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` which is bad or I can follow the advice found here [append dispathcer servlet mapping to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376392/append-dispatsher-servlet-mapping-to-url) and add line `request.setAttribute("frontControllerMapping", "controller/");` to every method which processes request and then code urls like this `${pageContext.request.contextPath}${frontControllerMapping}images/picture.jpg` which is better.

My questions are how to prepend the controller mapping to every url which must be processed by servlet and how to do it right? Is the second option the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the complete URL for each resource you can use relative URLs. If that is not an option, than you could simply map all requests to your servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet("/*")
```

Then you don't need to worry about adding the controller path to all URLs.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But, you see, I want to map a specific command to send image to client each time image appears on any page of an application. So it should be triggered by the same url, say `/image/imagename.jpg`. But if current url is like `localhost:8080/rootFolder/controller/page1/page2` then relative url will append after `page1` and controller will not trigger the right command.

Comment: ok, that rules out the relative urls, What about mapping all requests through the controller using the  /* mapping?

Comment: I saw from other posts that it is better not to map a front controller to the /* but to provide more specific url like /app/*. I tried using /* but it intercepted literally everything and I didn't figure out how to fix it by filtering or web.xml configuration.